# strange behavior when calling [NSOpenPanel openPanel]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos-sierra, nsopenpanel

Does anyone have an idea why calling [NSOpenPanel openPanel] can cause this:

2016-12-02 13:04:13.993030 MyApp[18817:1386980] !!! NSAccessibilityUnignoredDescendant - attempt to return ignored element: 
2016-12-02 13:04:13.993087 MyApp[18817:1386980] !!! Unable to override AXTitleUIElement on .  NSAccessibilityUnignoredDescendant returned nil.

Never seen anything like it?

Comment: Have you attempted to extend/modify `NSOpenPanel`, e.g. using categories or subclasses?

Comment: No I haven't changed anything...

Comment: You are probably going to need to show your code and describe the type of app you are building for anybody to be able to help.